# Incremental group number per specific hour in datetime attribute in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank, dense-rank

I have the table below.

```
create table timeTest(id, datetime)

insert into timeTest 
values (1, '2010-12-31 23:59:11.000'),
       (2, '2011-01-01 00:01:11.000'),
       (3, '2011-01-01 00:02:11.000'),
       (4, '2011-01-01 01:05:11.000')
```

I want to create a group number for each specific hour in the `datetime` attribute. So each hour in each year, month and day must be unique. I've tried this with the query below. But this query only gives a "1" value for each row.

```
SELECT 
    id, datetime, 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY datepart(year, (datepart(month,datepart(day, datepart(hour, datetime)))))) AS hourNumber
FROM
    timeTest
ORDER BY 
    hourNumber
```

The desired result must be:

```
id  datetime                     hourNumber
--------------------------------------------
1   2010-12-31 23:59:11.000      0
2   2011-01-01 00:01:11.000      1
3   2011-01-01 00:02:11.000      1
4   2011-01-01 01:05:11.000      2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank()`.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by cast(datetime as date), datepart(hour, datetime)) - 1 as hournumber
from timeTest  t;
```

Note:  This will ignore missing hours.  If you want the number of hours since the earliest hour, use `datediff()` instead:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(hour, min(datetime) over (), datetime) as hournumber
from timeTest  t;
```